# JTable  - why doesn't it keep the TableColumns after adding a row?

Tags: swing, jtable, tablemodel, nstablecolumn

I'm using a JTable :

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

public MyPanel () {
   init()
}


init () {
DataModel model = new DataModel();
JTable table = new JTable (model);

TableColumnModel tcm = agentsTable.getColumnModel();
        tcm.getColumn(FIRST).setPreferredWidth(15);
        tcm.getColumn(SECOND).setPreferredWidth(100);
        tcm.getColumn(THIRD).setPreferredWidth(200);


        JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane();
        scroller.getViewport().add(table);
        this.add(scroller, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

}


public class DataModel extends AbstractTableModel {

public final static int FIRST = 0;
public final static int SECOND = 1;
public final static int THIRD= 2;

...

}
```

the problem is every time i add a row to the model, the TableColumnModel seems to go back to default, and all the columns have the same width

Comment: @kleopatra your opening bracket `(` is not closed ~! :P

Comment: Why are you using `agentsTable` when getting the column model?  Your table is just called `table`.  Was that a mistake when copying your code over?

Comment: it was a mistake copying my code

Answer (score 2):

bet your custom TableModel fires a structureChanged on insert :-) That's incorrect, instead use [fireTableRowsInserted()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableRowsInserted%28int,%20int%29).

Comment: @AdiMor - okay, so I lost and the error is somewhere else :-) Show a SSCCE

Comment: @trashgod - thanks for adding the link! Just removed that ugly grey background again, it's hurting the reading flow (mine, it least :-)